# Syn Dihydroxylation of Alkenes

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

The answer makes sense to me. However, what if $\ce{OsO4}$ were to attack from the other side of the double bond? Why does the answer key not show that possibility? Would we not get an other molecule?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Attack from either side produces the same molecule.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look carefully you'll see that your compound has stereocenters, yet is achiral.  Both stereocenters have the opposite configuration.  This is the *meso*-form, these are achiral, and the hydroxy groups are prochiral.  Look carefully for the rotoinversion center!